# Pull & rebase from local branch

Tags: git

I would like to fetch all branches from the remote and then rebase my current branch on any changes to the master branch.

To do this, for some reason, I need to first checkout master, pull, and then go back to my current branch to rebase. Is there anyway to do this without having to switch branches?

Here is the workflow:

```
> git check_out main
> git checkout my_branch
> ...
> # do some work on my_branch
> ...
```

To then rebase on the latest changes to master, I can do the following:

### Option 1:

```
> # Update my master with remote master
> git checkout master
> git pull
> git checkout my_branch
> git rebase master
```

### Option 2 (without switching branches). It doesn't seem to work:

```
> git pull # Or git fetch
> # It complains with "There is no tracking information for the current branch"
> git rebase master
```

How can I rebase on master without switching branches?

Comment: If your only issue with option 1 is that it takes longer to type, you can always just set up a git [alias](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Git-Aliases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git rebase origin/master` to rebase on the fetched master branch (provided the remote name is origin).

Your local `master` branch will not be updated by that though, but once you check it out and pull it they will be in sync.

Comment: Thanks I am accepting this answer since it provides the actual solution to the problem in the OP, although Gareth goes a bit further into explaining what goes behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about this operation is that you are trying to update 2 local branches (both your `master` branch and your `my_branch`), where either branch may have conflicts to deal with – until you've fetched changes from the remote you don't know that the remote master is a clean fast-forward.

Since conflicts can only be resolved using a working copy, you need to perform each merge/rebase "from" the corresponding local branch.

Comment: Got it. That makes a lot of sense. It's just a bit tedious to switch branches. In my case, my `main` branch is just following (always `fast-forwarding`) the remote, so I was wondering if I could pull+rebase in one step, since the master merge should be trivial.

Comment: As @PerJohansson's answer suggests, you can rebase onto any point in the history tree, it doesn't have to be a local branch. So from `my_branch`: `git fetch [origin]; git rebase origin/master` will rebase your current branch. Then at a later stage `git checkout master; git merge my_branch` will bring your `master` branch up to date

Comment: Thanks. I see, I presume that `git rebase origin/master` will rebase on the **remote tracking branch** for `master` and not on the **local** `master`. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly! But now I'm just repeating the other answer :)

Comment: @user815423426: yes, but it's important to note that you rebase on to a *commit*, not on to a *branch*.  A branch *name* (label) is just a sticky note pasted on a particular commit.  The branch itself is the *chain of commits* starting from some commit and working backwards to a root.  When the label is at the tip of the branch, the label naming the tip commit, names the entire branch.